# How to delete record in m-m table

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

Have two entities Book and Genre, which have relations M-M = BookGenre.

BookGenre has two attributes BookId, GenreId. They are represented like foreign key, however they could be null.

SO! The question is, if i want to delete for Book specific GenreId, the record in this table will look like:

BookId Genre
1      null

Which looks so odd. And now, i'm looking for the solution to delete this thing, how is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will remove the whole records from BookGenre table. But Book and Genre records will remain in DB.

```
var booksToRemove= _dbContext.Set<BookGenre>().Where(i=> i.GenreId==1).ToArray();

_dbContext.Set<BookGenre>().RemoveRange(booksToRemove);

_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```